# How can i add Jenkinsfile support to visual studio 2017

Tags: jenkins, groovy, visual-studio-2017, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Pro, and i am being driven crazy by the lack of syntax highlighting for the Jenkinsfile in my project. I am using the Declarative Syntax, but i just cant seem to find anything on getting this to work. My research says that its based on groovy, but i dont see a way to map it to that language either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might wanna try IntellIJ instead, though it does not support Groovy highlighting 100% either.

Answer (score 10):

This might not be a solution for everyone, but for me, it worked:
Jenkinsfiles are the only files without extension I am working with, therefore I opened
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extensions
and then, I checked "Map extensionless files to:" and selected "Javascript Editor"

This does not require to install any extension and the display is great

Comment: Good stuff Jose.  Until the Visual Studio Code plugin is extended to support Visual Studio Enterprise (probably 2019), this is the best solution.

Comment: What does javascript have to do with jenkinsfiles?

Comment: @cowlinator: As stated in the question, Jenkinsfile syntax is based on Groovy and Groovy is a Java-syntax-compatible language [1]. But based on my experience, Groovy syntax fits better with what the text editors expect from Javascript than from Java. [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Groovy

Comment: This highlights great, but the limitless number of syntax errors shown is really annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same boat. Using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

I found [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=secanis.jenkinsfile-support) extension recently for Visual Studio Code and [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SyntaxHighlightingPack) extension for Visual Studio.

Comment: Good point with the link to the VS (not VSCode) extension. Although this ext supports Groovy it does not (yet) work for the file-extension-less Jenkinsfile. There is a pull request (https://github.com/madskristensen/TextmateBundleInstaller/pulls), but still pending. I tried updating the changes manually (re-installation with changed extension-source) but didn't work. Does it work for you somehow?

Comment: How did you set up the VS extension to get it to detect Jenkinsfiles? I couldn't figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: @ClausAppel.  I didn't in the end.

Comment: I guess I'll use VS Code for Jenkinsfiles for now, then. :)

Comment: No VS Code is a toy. Little better than notepad..  Use Visual Studio if you can

Comment: As of June 2019, the VS extension supports Jenkinsfiles.

Comment: The VS extension above isn't highlighting my JENKINSFILE in VS 2019. Anyone have alternative solutions in 2023?