# .jenkins code highlighting Visual Studio Code

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-code, codehighlighter

In our project we use `*.jenkins` files. How can I set syntax highlighting for Jenkinsfile?

I installed different Plugins, but per default they only support `Jenkinsfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question in [How can i add Jenkinsfile support to visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101688/how-can-i-add-jenkinsfile-support-to-visual-studio-2017/53608513)

Basically, I got it by setting the highlight of the *.jenkins files to be Javascript

Comment: This works, but the limitless number of syntax errors shown is really distracting and annoying.